# update a column by subtracting a value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to come up with a MySQL query that will update `points`... Can I do something like this?

```
UPDATE `a75ting`.`username` SET `points` = '`points` - 5'
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
UPDATE a75ting.username
SET points = points - 5
```

by putting the single quotes around the "points -5", you converted that expression into a plaintext string. Leaving it without the quotes lets MySQL see you're referring to a field (points) and subtracting 5 from its current value.

Comment: +1 for cathing the error **and** removing the unnecessary backticks

Comment: Note that this will affect zero rows if the value of points is null.  Therefore:  UPDATE a75ting.username SET points = ifnull(points,0) - 5;

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name backticks are helpful, if you did not give space between the keywords and table columns, the query will be executed. If you omit you should give space.

Answer (score 7):

Run this query to find out the difference:

```
SELECT '`points` - 5' AS string, `points` - 5 AS expression
FROM a75ting.username
```