# How to update value of a column as difference between two variables in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Here, update chooses bal(for balance) column of register table whose is to be changed to difference of bal and the value in variable $tax for only the row saisfying the condition. It's not working in following code.How to do it?

```
$query3 = mysql_query('update table register set  bal=bal-'.$tax.' where name='.$user.')' , $connection);
```

Comment: [Answer is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383108/update-a-column-by-subtracting-a-value).    

BTW, you should definitively forget about `mysql` extension and use PDO.

Comment: Yaa i ll try PDO next time.That link didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using in an incorrect way.

Try this:

```
$query3 = mysql_query("update table register set  bal=(bal-$tax) where name='$user'" , $connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, there is extra ')' after user, that hasn't '('