# Update a database field with Joomla UpdateObject method with a calculated field from same table

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

Right to the point.

I need to update a field in the database using the field to calculate the new value first.

E.g of fields: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FADH6.jpg

Now I am using the Joomla updateObject function. my goal is to take the "spent" value from the DB table without using a select statement.

Then I need to calculate a new value with it like (spent + 10.00) and update the field with the new value. Check out the code below:

```
// Create an object for the record we are going to update.
$object = new stdClass();

// Must be a valid primary key value.
$object->catid = $item['category'];
$object->spent = ($object->spent - $item['total']);

// Update their details in the users table using id as the primary key.
$result = JFactory::getDbo()->updateObject('#__mytable', $object, 'catid');
```

The bit which i need to make the calculation on is

```
$object->spent = ($object->spent - $item['total']);
```

I realise I can use a seperate insert statement but I am wondering if there is a better way. Any help  is much appreciated.

It needs to work like this, **WITHOUT THE SELECT** (working example)

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName('spent'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__mytable'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('catid')." = ". $item['category']);

// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);
$oldspent = $db->loadResult();

// Create an object for the record we are going to update.
$object = new stdClass();

// Must be a valid primary key value.
$object->catid = $item['category'];
$object->spent = ($oldspent - $item['total']);

// Update their details in the users table using id as the primary key.
$result = JFactory::getDbo()->updateObject('#__mytable', $object, 'catid');
```

Comment: Looks like a good question for [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Rather than providing screenshots of your database schema.  Please mock up a sqlfiddle for us with actual EXPORT structure and data from phpMyAdmin. Then tell us your exact desired result from your sample data. This makes your question super-clear by providing context and is "upvote-worthy" in my opinion.

Comment: @mickmacusa It would of been helpful to have a sqlfiddle page, but I didn't have time to build one. The screenshot shows the column "spent" which needed to be updated. It just needed to take the value which was there and update it with a new value after preforming a calculation on it. Was pretty straight forward.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2943403  Using the EXPORT tab in phpMyAdmin will take you about 2 minutes (including logging in) to "output as text" then paste the CREATE and INSERT queries into a demo, then post the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sticking point with trying to use `updateObject('#__mytable', $object, 'catid');` is that your query logic needs to reference the column name in the calculation to assign the "difference" as the new value.  The raw mysql query syntax to update a column value with the value minus another value is like:

```
"`spent` = `spent` - {$item['total']}"
```

`updateObject()` will convert `spent - {$item['total']}` to a literal string, the database will expect a numeric value, so UPDATE results in a `0` value recorded.  In other words, `$db->getAffectedRows()` will give you a positive count and there will be no errors generated, but you don't get the desired mathematical action.

The workaround is to discard `updateObject()` as a tool and build an UPDATE query without objects -- don't worry it's not too convoluted.  I'll build in some diagnostics and failure checking, but you can remove whatever parts that you wish.

I have tested the following code to be successful on my localhost:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
try {
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->update($db->quoteName('#__mytable'))
                ->set($db->quoteName("price") . " = " . $db->qn("price") . " - " . (int)$item['total'])
                ->where($db->quoteName("catid") . " = " . (int)$item['category']);
    echo $query->dump();  // see the generated query (but don't show to public)
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->execute();
    if ($affrows = $db->getAffectedRows()) {
        JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("Updated. Affected Rows: $affrows", 'success');
    } else {
        JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("Logic Error", 'error');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("Query Syntax Error: " . $e->getMessage(), 'error');  // never show getMessage() to public
}
```

Here is a StackOverflow page discussing the mysql subtraction logic: [update a column by subtracting a value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5383108/2943403)

Comment: this option works fine. but not exactly how I wanted it done. Not sure if what I asked could be done using updateObject.

Comment: I tried to explain how updateObject is used to nominate object keys as column names and values as column values.  Because your sql logic needs the new `price` value to be a mixture of a column name with a literal string, updateObject isn't equipped for the task (AFAIK).